# System.Windows.Application.Current returns null wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I have an application that has multiple windows. My goal is to call a radio button from a different window.
I'm trying to get all the windows and then select the specific window, then select the controls in that window and get the needed radio button.
I'm using a code like below:

```
System.Windows.Application myCurrentApp = System.Windows.Application.Current;

foreach (System.Windows.Window window in myCurrentApp.Windows.Cast<System.Windows.Window>().ToList())
{
// code
};
```

It fails as myCurrentApp is null:

> $exception    {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   System.NullReferenceException

Help greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: There is less chance for `Application.Current` to return null. Let us know in which event handler or code flow you are accessing that prop and getting null ?